# Generating quoted command arguments

Tags: shell-script, zsh, quoting, curl, arguments

I'm working with a HTTP API that demands a very particular set of signed headers + JSON body. And I really want to cURL it for debugging and sanity in general.

So, I've written a small script that, given the hostname, path and body, does all the mangling and then writes out what the cURL command line should be. eg.

```
./sign example.com /api/v1/foo/bar '{"foo":"bar"}'
example.com/api/v1/foo/bar -H 'x-sign:XXXXX', -H ... --data-binary '{"foo":"bar","sign":"xxx"}'
```

(Yes, it does seem quite complicated...)

I would expect this to be easily shell-able (in ZSH) thusly:

```
curl -v $(./sign ...)
```

But that gives me all sorts of quoting mistakes (or tries to curl the header-stuff as URLs, depending on how I do the quoting).

The only working way feels way too clunky to be ... real:

```
sh -c "curl -v $(./sign ...)"
```

I'm thinking I'm missing some fairly quoting-options of sorts here. Any pointers on how to get this "nice"?

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Would it be reasonable to have the shell script execute curl directly? You could use something like `set -x` to see the command as it's being executed. That way, you have one less level of quoting to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `./sign` outputs shell code, so it should be evaluated as such, either by `sh` with your `sh -c` or the current shell with `eval`:

```
eval "curl -v $(sign...)"
```

With `zsh` you can also only interpret the quoting in it (not do the expansions that that shell code may do) with:

```
curl -v "${(@Q)${(z)"$(sign)"}}"
```

Where `(z)` interprets the quoting, and `(Q)` removes the quotes (and `(@)` within quotes preserves the empty elements).

If `sign` outputs `"foo bar" "$(echo test)"`, the first one would call `curl` with `foo bar` and `test` as arguments, while the second one would call `curl` with `foo bar` and `$(echo test)` as arguments.